# How easily could this method of cryptography be cracked?

Tags: encryption

### Background

A couple of years back, in my naivety I dreamt up a method of encrypting information, the result can be seen [on my website](http://troydev.proggle.net/projects-steganography-and-cryptography.php), I evidentially thought it was pretty neat and I decided to mix it with steganographyto further confuse the issue.

Reality check, I know jack all about cryptography, most information on my page is probably wrong or at the very least misleading.

Ignoring the steganography, how easily could my method be cracked? (I'm guessing between easy and very easy, I just don't have the know how to be exact).

### Brief recap on how my method works

Assuming we are encoding characters,

1. Choose a number of bits to represent each encoded character
2. Choose a list of characters we will be able to encode
3. Generate a neural network which has 1 input for each bit (see 1) and one output for each character (see 2).
4. Make sure you use more bits (see 1) than characters (see 2).

The network takes a binary input and you take not the output as a whole but the strongest output, which maps directly to a character in your supported character list. Any set input will **always** map to the same output but, importantly, **multiple** inputs will map to **each** output.

If I am using 16 bits to encode 26 characters, I'll have 65,535 unique inputs mapping to just 26 outputs, or 2,520 ways to represent each character.

This means the letter 'z' 2,520 times could be encoded as a non-repeating set of 16-bit integers.

### Flaws I can see

- If you can recreate the neural network, you can decode the information, this involves keeping a secret, the algorithm and inputs used to generate the network (or the exact network used if crafted manually). Is this any worse than other encryption methods?
- There are likely to be similarities between the groups of inputs which result in the same character.
- Having no repeating patterns, is probably a weak point, no pattern is probably as revealing as an obvious pattern.

### The question

How easily could this method of cryptography be cracked? Feel free to rip it apart, it is an amateur attempt after all.

Comment: We now have https://cryptography.stackexchange.com for questions like this. A neural network *is* an algorithm, so the strength of the encryption depends on the network.

Comment: If i understand it correctly this is similiar to the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) with random mapping and a bigger characterset. This should be easily cracked by a [known plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack).

Comment: Actually, it's a simple substitution cipher (Ceasar cipher uses a fixed position shift in the alphabet). Plain text attacks are one way to crack it but you can also use frequency analysis. As always, I feel obligated to quote "law zero" of application security: **don't attempt to roll out your own crypto**

Comment: @Stephane It was more of a project for fun, I'm not attempting to use it anywhere, fear not!

Answer (score 0):

The point of this Q&A site is not to assess people's algorithm strength, so technically this question is off-topic. However, there are points in here that requires explanation and do point to the algorithm weakness without having to look at it.

As per [Kerckhoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle), a cryptographic system must still be secure if everything about the system is known, except the key. "What is the key" in your case? And "what is it's length?" are two question you need to ask yourself before even thinking of strength of the scheme.

The network seems to be the real key here. It is based on a pseudo-random generator. So the key is the seed. Which is an int. So 32 bits. That is a poor key.

In addition, having both plain text and it's encrypted form makes it possible to make a known plaintext attack (as mentioned in the comments).

So it's a bad cryptography scheme.

Furthermore, steganography and cryptography rarely goes well together, since they have objectives that are opposed. Cryptography is all about confidentiality (and authenticity in the case of signature), while steganography wants to stay undetected in the mass of information. Steganography does not care about strong resistance to decryption, in fact the algorithm can be published and not use any key at all. The "security" behind steganography is resumed by the following elements:

- You have a flow of data (images, ...) that is important
- The attacker cannot plausibly try to decrypt each and every data to check for hidden message
- The steganography scheme does modifications that are not easily identified in the data

The goal of the attacker of a steganography scheme is to be able to process an image and say : "yes there is a message here", or "no there is no message here".

Typically, cryptography is used to transmit large amount of data. But large amount of data cannot be successfully hidden with steganography in only one media without impairing invisibility.

Furthermore, your scheme increases the number of bits needed to be embedded.

So it's a bad steganography algorithm.